# PICC18: Certain __CONFIG() -macros cause syntax errors

Tags: pic, c, compiler, hi-tech-compiler

```
  __CONFIG(0, 0xFFFF);
  __CONFIG(1, FOSC_HS  );
  __CONFIG(2, BOREN_OFF);
  __CONFIG(3, WDTEN_OFF);
  __CONFIG(4, 0xFFFF);
  __CONFIG(5, 0xFFFF);
> __CONFIG(6, CP0_OFF && CP1_OFF);
> __CONFIG(7, CPB_OFF && CPD_OFF);
> __CONFIG(8, WRT0_OFF && WRT1_OFF);
> __CONFIG(9, WRTC_OFF && WRTB_OFF && WRTD_OFF);
> __CONFIG(10, EBTR0_OFF && EBTR1_OFF);
  __CONFIG(11, EBTRB_OFF);
```

The rows that I have marked cause a syntax error while building, others are fine.

```
C:\Users\Oppilas\AppData\Local\Temp\s6bc.:14: error: syntax error
```

I am using HI-TECH PICC-18 PRO v9.66, lite mode.

Comment: Here's the sort of question you'd find in an IQ test: find one thing the problematic lines have in common.

Comment: @Armandas I was going to answer read- or writeprotection :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I thought I'll answer properly :)

The `&&` is a logical operator and the result is boolean. This does not make any sense in this case. What you need is `&` (a bit-wise operator).

Comment: Oh wow, good one.  This is one of those problems you can stare at for a whole day and never figure out.

Comment: @AngryEE I once typed `|=` instead of `!=` in a condition. Now that took me a while to find.